# Is there a way to use the pug.render() function from a cdn import?

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I am trying to borrow the `pug.render()` function from pug and am attempting to cdn import it like so

`<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pug@3.0.2/lib'></script>`

to then use in another script on the same page

```
function test() {
let textarea1 = document.querySelector('#pug')
let textarea2 = document.querySelector('#html')
textarea2.value = render(textarea1.value, {pretty: '  '}) 
}
```

and then have a button click call the test function like so:
`<button onclick='test()'></button>`

Documentation doesn't say anything and any google search is for script importing in pug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up stumbling on this solution.
you have to do

`<script src = 'https://pugjs.org/js/pug.js'></script>`

and then in the following script tag do

```
const p = require('pug');
// what ever you want to do
p.render(args)
```

You need to do this even if you don't have access to `require`. It will not work if you were do to `render()` without the require statement.